# How to pass date parameters in java script

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to pass date pareamters through CDATA but it is not displaying any data through Postman.

The query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Queries>
  <Action Name="Report_1" RootTag="response">
    <TagsToRemoveFromOutput>
      <Tag></Tag>
    </TagsToRemoveFromOutput>
    <CodeToDescription>
    </CodeToDescription>
    <Query Name="TestReport_query" TableTag="TestReport" RecordTag="row_data" ReturnEmptyTagForNullString="Yes" TagCase="Lower">

     <CommandText>
        <![CDATA[
    select  id,id_value,date as fromdate
    from TAB_CUST
    where trunc(date )>to_date(:start_date:,'YYYY-MM-DD') and trunc(crtn_dt)<to_date(:end_date:,'YYYY-MM-DD') 

    ]]>
      </CommandText>

    </Query>
  </Action>
</Queries>
```

If I am trying through postman(tool) I am not getting any results it is showing result as NULL.

Postman Parameters:

```
<parameter><name>start_date</name><value>2017-01-01</value></parameter>
    <parameter><name>end_date</name><value>2017-03-01</value></parameter>
```